# Fix problem of long URL when changing the dynamic style of a WMS?

Tags: javascript, wms, sld, vue.js

I have created a Vue.js application that uses an OpenLayers map and I want to integrate a WMS layer that can dynamically change its style. My WMS layer displays the carbon emission of many entities of the world (countries, states, etc.) depending on the zoom level on the map. If you zoom out to the maximum only large federations will be displayed (Europe, China, Russia, etc.) and if you zoom in you will see the countries or regions of these federations (Spain, UK, states of USA).

To change the style after the corresponding zoom level I use the updateParams() function of the TileWMS class and I generate an xml style that I pass to the sld_body parameter of the query on my WMS layer. But when all the countries and regions of the federations are displayed the generated xml is very long and my request ends up with a URI too long error.

Here is the generated XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<NamedLayer>
    <Name>cite:v_province</Name>
    <UserStyle>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_province</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>9</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>46</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>106</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>70</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#FFEDA0</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_province</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>52</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>36</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>41</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>74</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>84</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>78</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>95</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>49</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>31</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>83</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>34</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>102</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>86</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>15</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>65</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>104</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>57</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>60</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>53</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>87</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>54</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>23</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>47</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>98</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>33</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>48</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>14</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>43</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>73</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>96</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>109</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>93</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>24</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>58</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>63</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>11</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>64</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>37</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>105</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>26</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#FD8D3C</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_province</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>101</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>110</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>77</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>80</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>331</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>108</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>85</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>103</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>94</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>72</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>39</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>19</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>61</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>89</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>91</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>92</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>71</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>97</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#FC4E2A</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_province</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>35</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>7</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>45</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>21</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>55</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>69</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>28</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>22</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>38</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>82</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>13</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>76</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>29</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>68</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>59</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>99</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>75</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>51</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>17</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>27</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>32</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>81</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#FEB24C</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_province</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>42</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>88</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>56</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>67</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>30</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#FED976</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_province</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>66</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>79</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>44</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>62</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#E31A1C</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
<NamedLayer>
    <Name>cite:v_static</Name>
    <UserStyle>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_static</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>9</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#E31A1C</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_static</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#FD8D3C</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>cite:v_static</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:Function name="in">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#FC4E2A</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
```

How can I change my request so that passing a long XML is not a problem?

Comment: make a POST request instead of a GET

Comment: How do you do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Write the style to a web location accessible by the WMS server and use the `SLD` parameter instead of the `SLD_BODY` parameter to provide a URL to the SLD.